# Where's `CurrentTime` defined? How do I get it?

Tags: c, x11, xrandr

I'm trying to write a rudementary program to rotate the screen (using libXrandr). I couldn't find a lot of info about libXrandr, outside of `xrandr`'s source code and man pages. So, I decided to analyze [`xrandr`'s source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/-/blob/master/xrandr.c) to learn about libXrandr.

Upon writing the initialization routines, I came across `XRRSetScreenConfig`, that calls for a `Timestamp` parameter:

```c
Status XRRSetScreenConfig (Display *dpy,
            XRRScreenConfiguration *config,
            Drawable draw,
            int size_index,
            Rotation rotation,
            Time timestamp);
```

I've got all the parameters figured out, except for the last one, `timestamp`. I looked around xrandr.c for uses of the function to point me in the right direction to what's supposed to be passed to it, and I found that a variable (?) named `CurrentTime` is passed in place of this parameter:

```c
status = XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate (dpy, sc, root, (SizeID) size,
    (Rotation) (rotation | reflection),
    rate, CurrentTime);
```

(btw `XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate` has the same params as `XRRSetScreenConfig`, except with a couple extra parameters)

I looked around for where this variable is set, but I literally couldn't find *anywhere* where it's set, or even *defined*. Not even in Xrandr.h or its sub-includes.

So, I guess what my question is, what is `CurrentTime`? Is it literally just the current time in Unix time? Can I pass just a regular `time_t` timestamp to `XRRSetScreenConfig`? If not, how do I obtain a valid `CurrentTime`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use utilities like `cscope` to build source-indexing & search for tokens among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CurrentTime` is a macro defined in the `X11/X.h` header, which is subsequently included by `X11/Xlib.h`. So you can just pass in that `CurrentTime` in your program without worrying about *where* and *how* it is defined.

Comment: It so happens that it is defined as `0L`.  Presumably functions that take a `Time` argument know to handle 0 as a special case.